# opencv face detection (real-time) on iPhone Camera

Tags: ios4, opencv

Is there any suggestion where I can find some source codes or a place to start at ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to follow [this](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/08/09/near-realtime-face-detection-on-the-iphone-w-opencv-port-wcodevideo) post

Also I recommend [this blog](http://computer-vision-talks.com/) to start with OpenCV on iPhone